# use \ref{#1}c instead of \cref{#1} (using \futurelet)

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to use `\ref{#1}c` instead of `\cref{#1}` for some autocompletion issues.

I have been trying to implement this using the following code:

```
\let\oldref\ref
\def\ref{\futurelet\@nexttoken\myref}
\def\myref#1{\if c\@nexttoken\creftemp{#1}\else\oldref{#1}\fi}
\def\creftemp#1c{\cref{#1}}
```

But the result doesn't change. What's wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\let\oldref\ref
\def\ref{\futurelet\@nexttoken\myref}
\def\myref#1{\if c\@nexttoken\creftemp{#1}\else\oldref{#1}\fi}
\def\creftemp#1c{\cref{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[sdfs] \label{sdf} asfa \end{theorem}

\cref{sdf} = theorem 1

\ref{sdf}c = theorem 1

\ref{sdf} c = 1 c

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would not use \@ifnextchar because it ignores spaces

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a minimum working example so that we don't each have to create all the necessary filling that your question lacks?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several shortcomings in your definition. You need to first absorb the argument to `\ref` and only after it check whether a `c` follows.

Also the conditional should end *before* calling the “gobbling” macro.

Finally, `\ref` gets redefined by `hyperref` at begin document, so your own redefinition should be delayed.

Another small issue is the usage of `\let` with the `\ref` command that `hyperref` makes robust; here I use `\NewCommandCopy` that's been available for more than a year; if your TeX distribution is older, use `\LetLtxMacro` from the `letltxmacro` package.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy{\old@ref}{\ref}%
  \def\ref#1{\def\temp@ref{#1}\futurelet\@nexttoken\new@ref}%
}
\def\new@ref{%
  \if c\noexpand\@nexttoken
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\cref@eatc{\temp@ref}}%
  {\old@ref{\temp@ref}}%
}
\def\cref@eatc#1c{\cref{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[sdfs] \label{sdf} asfa \end{theorem}

\cref{sdf} = theorem 1

\ref{sdf}c = theorem 1

\ref{sdf} c = 1 c

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why `\noexpand`? Because you don't want to expand the following token which might be a macro or `~`.

You may appreciate an `expl3` version of the same, which is easier to implement, but not conceptually different.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\AtBeginDocument
  {
    \NewCommandCopy{\__refc_saved_ref:n}{\ref}
    \cs_set_eq:NN \ref \__refc_new_ref:n 
  }

\tl_new:N \l__refc_arg_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__refc_new_ref:n
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__refc_arg_tl { #1 }
    \peek_charcode_remove:NTF c
      {
        \exp_args:NV \cref \l__refc_arg_tl
      }
      {
        \exp_args:NV \__refc_saved_ref:n \l__refc_arg_tl
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[sdfs] \label{sdf} asfa \end{theorem}

\cref{sdf} = theorem 1

\ref{sdf}c = theorem 1

\ref{sdf} c = 1 c

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Based on your answer, I could further simplify it: `\AtBeginDocument{%
\NewCommandCopy{\old@ref}{\ref}
\def\ref#1{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace c{\cref@eatc{#1}}{\old@ref{#1}}}
\def\cref@eatc#1c{\cref{#1}}
}`

Answer (score 4):

Here I use a token cycle to obtain the result.  For proper behavior with `hyperref`, the redefinition of `\ref` must be placed `\AtBeginDocument`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\let\oldref\ref
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\tcpushliteral[1]{\tcpush{\noexpand#1}}
\stripgroupingtrue

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\ref[1]{%
  \tokencycle
  {\ifx c##1\tcpush{\cref{#1}}\else\tcpush{\oldref{#1}##1}\fi
    \tcpushliteral{\endtokcycraw}}
  {\tcpushliteral{\truncatenow{##1}}}
  {\ifx\truncatenow##1\else
    \tcpush{##1}\fi\tcpush{\oldref{#1}}%
    \tcpushliteral{\endtokcycraw}}
  {\tcpush{\oldref{#1}##1}\tcpushliteral{\endtokcycraw}}%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[sdfs] \label{sdf} asfa \end{theorem}

\cref{sdf} = theorem 1

\ref{sdf}c = theorem 1

\ref{sdf} c = 1 c

\ref{sdf}x = 1x

\ref{sdf}\today = 1\today

\ref{sdf}{\itshape d}x = 1{\itshape d}x
\end{document}
```

[image]